# Get rid of the wrap of the extension content in extbase

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I have an extbase extension, and i'm inserting it in a typoscript :

```
lib.content = USER
lib.content{
        userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
        pluginName = plugin
        extensionName = extension
        vendorName = TYPO3
}
```

The problem is, i have a wrap on my content : `<div class="my_extension_key">` and i couldn't find it in the typoscript object browser!

Can you please help me to find this wrap, so i can delete it!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Extbase extension, the wrap usually is in

```
myextensions/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html
```

You need to copy the Layouts folder to your site templates, change it and adjust the layoutRootPath of the extension.